What is the stronger emotion - to be annoyed or to be bothered?
On the scale of being angry which is a more extreme feeling- to be annoyed or to be bothered by something?

Where their respective ranges of application overlap, annoyed is a stronger term than bothered.
But one can be bothered by a thing that it wouldn’t even be likely to include among things that might annoy one. Thus, I might feel bothered that a friend had become ill, but could only find it annoying if, for example, I blamed the friend or were angry at her for becoming ill.

It's often quicker to get over an annoyance, than to be bothered by sth, which might be a longer-term emotion that niggles continuously until solved.

Don't get all hot and bothered.  I think bothered can go either way.  A momentary slight annoyance or a festering irksome thing. Something has been really bothering me lately.

It depends on how the words are being used. There's no abstract absolute scale they can be placed on.

Something has been really bothering me lately, weighing heavy on my mind.
I'll cook dinner tonight since you've been doing the laundry.
-- Oh, it's no bother. I love the fresh spring smell of Tide™.
That fly kept buzzing around my head all during the pastor's sermon. I don't know what made me more annoyed, that fly or his dull story.
The frat boys upstairs have been playing their pounding stereo all night. It makes me so effin annoyed. It's 2AM, dammit.


None of your examples show bothered as stronger than annoyed.

@deep64blue  Did I say it was stronger? No. I said there is no absolute scale and you have to see how it's being used. I showed examples of bother where it's mild and examples where the emotional degree is quite extreme.
